# Integer sequence, in which I have to find the most repeated one. Incase of many repeated numbers, find the lowest value

Tags: c#

Theres an integer sequence in which I have to find the most repeated value. Incase of many repeated values, find the lowest value of all the repeated values.

Example: Incase of {-10,17,13,17,-10,21} the result is -10

How far I've got so far:

```
        static void YL2()
    {
        Random random = new Random();

        int mitu = 10, minv = 0, maxv = 20;
        int[] mas1 = new int[mitu];
        int i;
        int lowest;


        for (i = 0; i < mitu; i++) mas1[i] = random.Next(minv, maxv);
        for (i = 0; i < mitu; i++)
            Console.Write("{0,4}", mas1[i]);
        Console.Write("\n\n");

        int count = 0;
        List<int> checkedNumbers = new List<int>();


        foreach (int t in mas1)
        {
            if (!checkedNumbers.Contains(t))
            {
                foreach (int m in mas1)
                {
                    if (m == t)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Number {0} is repeated {1} times", t, count);
                count = 0;
                checkedNumbers.Add(t);
            }
        }

        for (lowest = mas1[0], i = 1; i < mitu; i++)
        {
            if (mas1[i] < lowest) lowest = mas1[i];
        }
        Console.Write("Lowest value is {0}\n\n", lowest);

    }
```

Comment: Ok, and what is the question?

Comment: Sorry,
Currently I've made it show the repeated values and the lowest value in the whole sequence.
I would like help with making it show the lowest value within the repeated values, incase there is more than 1 repeating value.

Comment: Do you mean the lowest _any_ number that appears more than once, or only if two numbers appear the same number of times? Eg. from `{1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3}` do you expect `1` or `2`?

Comment: The expected would be 1.

Comment: Even though `2` and `3` are repeated more often? You do say you want the _most repeated value_.

Answer (score 1):

The Linq way:

```
var lowestMaxCountDuplicate = sequence
               .GroupBy(i => i)
               .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
               .ThenBy(g => g.Key)
               .First().Key;
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/hCmraU)

Answer (score 1):

The way that doesn't involve replacing all your code you've written with LINQ, as you've done a lot of it yourself:

In your declarations, replace `int lowest;` with

```
bool foundOne = false;
int lowest = int.MaxValue;
```

and we'll keep track of the lowest repeated number as we go along.

After your `Console.WriteLine("Number {0} is repeated {1} times", t, count);`, add

```
if (count > 1 && t < lowest)
{
     foundOne = true;
     lowest = t;
}
```

i.e. if the number is repeated and it's lower than the lowest repeated number we've found so far, store this one instead. Also, we keep track of whether we've found *any* repeated numbers. Note that because we set `lowest` to `int.MaxValue` to begin with, the first repeated number we found will always be lower than it (*or* it's the same, in which case it's correct anyway).

Then at the end, rather than your `for` loop, have the following:

```
if (foundOne)
    Console.Write("Lowest repeated value is {0}\n\n", lowest);
else
    Console.Write("No repeated values found\n\n");
```

just in case every number was different.

This *is* less effecient than the LINQ, because you're looping through your list far more than you need to, but I thought you might like a solution that doesn't throw away everything you've done.